# How to extract CDATA nested inside a comment from an HTML cURL response using PHP

Tags: php, regex, xpath, comments, domdocument

So, I have a cURL response in html fomrat such as this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head profile="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--//
      -->
      <![CDATA[//><!--
      window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js'>\x3C/script>")
      //--><!]]>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--//
      -->
      <![CDATA[//><!--
      jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"locmexfront","theme_token":"Yp7MPwcD_S9ylvcMePWcxqlLisY8L47THKWrSzn_7po","js":{"https:\/\/ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/1.7.1\/jquery.min.js":1,"0":1,"misc\/jquery.once.js":1,"misc\/drupal.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/custom\/locmex\/chosen.jquery.min.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/custom\/locmex\/js_universal.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/custom\/locmex\/locmxjs2.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/fancybox\/fancybox.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/source\/jquery.fancybox.pack.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/lib\/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js":1,"https:\/\/www.google.com\/jsapi":1,"https:\/\/domain.com:12363\/socket.io\/socket.io.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/nodejs\/nodejs.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/drupalchat\/drupalchat_nodejs\/drupalchat_nodejs.js":1,"https:\/\/maps.googleapis.com\/maps\/api\/js?libraries=drawing\u0026key=AIzaSyBjs2UjXiSoMvOl5H2St8uPfSFtUVMVM5c\u0026libraries=places,drawing":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/custom\/locmex\/markerwithlabel.js":1,"\/sites\/all\/modules\/custom\/locmex\/compartir.js":1},"css":{"modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/calendar\/css\/calendar_multiday.css":1,"modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/date\/date_api\/date.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/date\/date_popup\/themes\/datepicker.1.7.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/date\/date_repeat_field\/date_repeat_field.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/esign\/css\/esign.css":1,"modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/logintoboggan\/logintoboggan.css":1,"modules\/node\/node.css":1,"modules\/user\/user.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views\/css\/views.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/css\/ckeditor.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/css\/ctools.css":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/source\/jquery.fancybox.css":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fontawesome\/css\/font-awesome.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/fonts\/font-awesome\/css\/font-awesome.min.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/client.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/fancybox.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/font.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/ie.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/normalize.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/plugins.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/reset.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/styles.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/bootstrap.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/style.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/chosen.css":1}},"fancybox":{"options":{"minWidth":500,"minHeight":250},"helpers":{"title":{"type":"inside"}},"selectors":["a.lightbox"]},"nodejs":{"nodejs":{"scheme":"https","secure":1,"host":"domain.com","port":"12363"},"client":{"scheme":"https","secure":1,"host":"domain.com","port":"12363"},"resource":"\/socket.io","authToken":"2d96246251c006a34561300e8e16b699","websocketSwfLocation":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/nodejs\/socket_io\/socket.io\/support\/socket.io-client\/lib\/vendor\/web-socket-js\/WebSocketMain.swf","log_http_errors":true},"locmex":{"units":{"unit_91505":{"name":"32","unit_id":"92505","icon":"https:\/\/domain.com\/sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/img\/0.png","servidor":2}},"hash":"88a15b1aef0a8883b47777748458abfdd"}});
      //--><!]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="html not-front">
    <div id="skip-link">
      <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="user_relationships_popup_form" class="user_relationships_ui_popup_form"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I´m trying to get the information inside the Script tag.... the JSON part of it, the one that comes just after `jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings,`  I have tried using XPath and have been able to get the `<script>` tag node and use the `textContent` property to get the content, then try to apply some `preg_replace` to remove the unwanted characters, but it does not work...

UPDATE: i to ended up using REGEX such as @Kinglish but a a different way... So here is what I end up using.

```
$scripts_array = array();
$tst_array = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@ $dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//head/script') as $script){
  $script_text = $script->textContent;
  preg_match('/(.*), (.*)/', $script_text, $tst);
  if (!empty($tst)) {
    $tst_array[]=$tst;
  }
}
$res = $tst_array[0][2];
$resjson = substr($res, 0, -2);
$data = json_decode($resjson, true);
```

Comment: Hi, please post the code you have tried, and elaborate on "does not work".

Comment: Thank you... so I tried using xpath and domdocument method to extract CDATA, but it always returned empty because CDATA is inside comment characters.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't regex, but I think much easier...

```
    <?php
    $scripts = [];
    $html = explode('<![CDATA[//>', $html);
    unset($html[0]);
    $rep = ['<!--', '-->', '</script>'];
    foreach ($html as $seg) {
        foreach ($rep as $r)  $seg = str_replace($r, '', $seg);
        $seg = explode('//<!]]>', $seg)[0];
        $scripts[]=trim($seg);
    }
    print_r($scripts);
```

example: https://www.tehplayground.com/L086vbUqlKom5nTU

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js'>")
    [1] => jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"locmexfront","theme_token":"Yp7MPwcD_S9ylvcMePWcxqlLisY8L47THKWrSzn_7po","js":{"https:\/\/ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/1.7.1\/jquery.min.js":1,"0":1,"misc\/jquery.once.js":1,"misc\/drupal.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/custom\/locmex\/chosen.jquery.min.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/custom\/locmex\/js_universal.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/custom\/locmex\/locmxjs2.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/fancybox\/fancybox.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/source\/jquery.fancybox.pack.js":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/lib\/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js":1,"https:\/\/www.google.com\/jsapi":1,"https:\/\/domain.com:12363\/socket.io\/socket.io.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/nodejs\/nodejs.js":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/drupalchat\/drupalchat_nodejs\/drupalchat_nodejs.js":1,"https:\/\/maps.googleapis.com\/maps\/api\/js?libraries=drawing\u0026key=AIzaSyBjs2UjXiSoMvOl5H2St8uPfSFtUVMVM5c\u0026libraries=places,drawing":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/custom\/locmex\/markerwithlabel.js":1,"\/sites\/all\/modules\/custom\/locmex\/compartir.js":1},"css":{"modules\/system\/system.base.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.menus.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.messages.css":1,"modules\/system\/system.theme.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/calendar\/css\/calendar_multiday.css":1,"modules\/comment\/comment.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/date\/date_api\/date.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/date\/date_popup\/themes\/datepicker.1.7.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/date\/date_repeat_field\/date_repeat_field.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/esign\/css\/esign.css":1,"modules\/field\/theme\/field.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/logintoboggan\/logintoboggan.css":1,"modules\/node\/node.css":1,"modules\/user\/user.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/views\/css\/views.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ckeditor\/css\/ckeditor.css":1,"sites\/all\/modules\/ctools\/css\/ctools.css":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fancybox\/source\/jquery.fancybox.css":1,"sites\/all\/libraries\/fontawesome\/css\/font-awesome.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/fonts\/font-awesome\/css\/font-awesome.min.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/client.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/fancybox.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/font.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/ie.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/normalize.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/plugins.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/reset.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/styles.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/bootstrap.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/style.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/css\/chosen.css":1}},"fancybox":{"options":{"minWidth":500,"minHeight":250},"helpers":{"title":{"type":"inside"}},"selectors":["a.lightbox"]},"nodejs":{"nodejs":{"scheme":"https","secure":1,"host":"domain.com","port":"12363"},"client":{"scheme":"https","secure":1,"host":"domain.com","port":"12363"},"resource":"\/socket.io","authToken":"2d96246251c006a34561300e8e16b699","websocketSwfLocation":"\/sites\/all\/modules\/nodejs\/socket_io\/socket.io\/support\/socket.io-client\/lib\/vendor\/web-socket-js\/WebSocketMain.swf","log_http_errors":true},"locmex":{"units":{"unit_91505":{"name":"32","unit_id":"92505","icon":"https:\/\/domain.com\/sites\/all\/themes\/locmexfront\/img\/0.png","servidor":2}},"hash":"88a15b1aef0a8883b47777748458abfdd"}});
)
```

Comment: Thank you... this is one way to get it. Just need trimming.